# Mongoengine - use multiple connections for migration

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, fastapi

I am new to MongoDB and trying to migrate data between two.
So I can connect to DB A and query - but my question is how can I connect to B and copy content from A -> B ? I found this

[mongoengine connection and multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584024/mongoengine-connection-and-multiple-databases)

but it states that models are specific to each database to use the `meta` tag.

Setting up two connections and copying the same model rather than dumping A to disk and reading into B. I have no CLI access to both, so I can not pipe the file in (if that's an option at all like with SQL), hence thinking of a trigger in my `FastAPI` on B to pull from A.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's probably easier to use `pymongo` directly for this operation as is way easier and you don't need to parse the doc in a mongoengine model.

```
c1 = MongoClient('mongodb://host1:27017/')
c2 = MongoClient('mongodb://host2:27017/')
for doc in c1.firstdabase.somecollection.find():
      c2.seconddatabase.somecollection.insert(doc)
```

The code above is a rough solution. Depending on you data volume you should probably look for batching: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html

Comment: Thanks, but we are running `mongoengine` in the project. That is a set thing...

Comment: Mongoengie uses pymongo behind the scenes. You can use your model to get the objects and use pymongo to insert in the second one for example.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that... Mongo newbie. Will look closer into it then.

Comment: Here is a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068558/use-mongoengine-and-pymongo-together